# Is the call ApplicationContext.getBean() in Spring using dependency injection?

Tags: java, spring

Since dependency injection imply an inversion of control, I can't see an IOC in the following call:

```
  Car car = (Car)ApplicationContext.getBean("car");
```

It's not Spring to work out itself the class, because I wrote Car myself into the code.

Moreover, all the books talk about two kind of DI: setter and constructor DI.

So I was wondering if the call ApplicationContext.getBean() imply any kind of dependency injection and IOC or there is no DI at all.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Getting your bean this way is not dependency injection.  It is not getting injected.  The fields of that bean are probably injected though.

Sometimes there's really no way around it, but in general, try to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

> It's not Spring to work out itself the class, because I wrote Car myself into the code.

In that case you'd get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. You need to tell Spring about every class that it needs to manage -- there are multiple ways to do this, from autowiring to explicit definition in a descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

The `getBean` does use the same configuration (`applicationContext`) than Spring's injection would use, but your example is not using any dependency injection. (Well the `Car` bean could be injected with it's dependencies so we don't really know from your example).

But normally dependency injection means you don't do any programmatic setting (Car car = something ) by yourself. The Spring container will create the `car` instance for you and either using the `car`'s setters or it's constructor, will inject the dependencies the x needs to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are trying to get the Car reference in this manner...If you want to use the reference of Car in another class, you can simply use setter or constructor injection as you said..If you use it as in the above manner, I can't see any kind of DI there.One thing we can surely say is that,the bean is managed by the IOC container as you are trying to get the reference from the application context...